# iGraph Count Number of Edges with a given vertex

Tags: python-3.x, igraph

I want to count the number of edges that any arbitrary vertex `v` has connected to it. How can I do this? I haven't found a function that does this in the [docs](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#get_edgelist). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question (like me today) and would still like an answer:

```
g = ig.Graph()
... (do stuff)
g.vs.select(name_eq = <vertex_name>).degree()
```

Here I selected a vertex based on its name attribute (the _eq is used by the select function), but this could be any vertex attribute you choose.

Have a look at [iGraph degree function](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph._igraph.GraphBase.html#degree)
And [iGraph select](https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.VertexSeq.html#select) for more information